# Looking for code to pull data from column A when any cell in colums B through AH are not null

Tags: excel, vba

I have two spreadsheets. One is empty, the other contains data. I open both and need to pull data from the one containing data, pasting into the blank spreadsheet. Criteria is to copy cell A when any cell from B through AH is not null and paste the data from cell A into the blank spreadsheet. The number of rows varies. Cells B - AH would either be null or contain an integer (1 - 5). If ANY cell in B - AH contains an integer, I need to copy cell A to the blank spreadsheet.

I know how to find the last cell and loop from row 1 to lastcell but not sure how I would loop through columns B - AH to find the first not null cell.

I'm thinking it would be best to create an array to store cell A when the criteria is met then, when complete, move to the blank spreadsheet and paste the array. Just not sure how I would code the search for any not null cells in each row.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you want. It determines the presence of integers in the B:AH range by using the worksheet function COUNT().

```
Private Sub CountIntegers()

    Dim Arr As Variant                  ' output array
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rl As Long                      ' last row
    Dim R As Long                       ' row counter
    Dim i As Long                       ' index of Arr

    With ActiveSheet
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim Arr(1 To Rl)
        For R = 2 To Rl                 ' assuming row 1 to have headers
            Set Rng = Range(.Cells(R, "B"), .Cells(R, "AH"))
            If Application.Count(Rng) Then
                i = i + 1
                Arr(i) = .Cells(R, "A").Value
            End If
        Next R
    End With

    ReDim Preserve Arr(i)
    ' specify the output sheet here:-
    Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1).Resize(i)
    Rng.Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
End Sub
```